# prove the inverse image of a maximal ideal is also a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The following is the problem:

> Let $K$ be a field, and $A$ is a commutative ring containing $K$. $\phi:A \rightarrow K[X]$ is a ring homomorphism which is the identity on $K$. If $M$ is a maximal ideal of $K[X]$, show that $\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

I tried to prove that $A/\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a field. Since $K[X]$ is a PID, $M$ should be generated by some irreducible polynomial $g(X)\in K[X].$ Because the indeterminate $X$ is transcendental over $K$, $\phi^{-1}(X)$ should be another indeterminate, say $Y$ in $A$. Hence $\phi^{-1}(M)$ is generated by the irreducible polynomial $g(Y)\in K[Y]$, which makes $A/\phi^{-1}(M)$ isomorphic to a simple extension $K(\alpha),$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $g(Y).$ So $A/\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a field and $\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a maximal ideal.

Are there any mistakes in my argument? Please let me know if there are any problems in it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi^{-1}(X)$? You're not assuming $\phi$ to be bijective.

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice this, so I should write it like that. I'm not sure right now how to deal with it if $\phi^{-1}(X)$ doesn't make sense...

Comment: If you consider the composite morphism $A \to K[X] \to K[X]/M$, then $A/\phi^{-1}(M)$ is isomorphic to the image of $A$ under that morphism. Let me also comment on your wording: $\phi^{-1}(M)$ isn't the "inverse" of $M$. It's the *inverse image* of $M$ under $\phi$, or the *pullback* of $M$.

Comment: It's so neat! So with the composite morphism $\Phi$ you suggested, we have that $A/\phi^{-1}(M)$ is isomorphic to $\Phi(A)$, which is a subring  of $K[X]/M$ containing $K$. Since $K[X]/M$ and $K$ are fields, it can be proved that $A/\phi^{-1}(M)$ in between is also a field. Does it sound right?

Comment: You need to know not only that $K[X]/M$ and $K$ are fields but that $K[X]/M$ is an algebraic extension of $K$.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: Yes, thank you for pointing it out. We do need that. Use some argument above, $K[X]/M$ should be isomorphic to an algebraic extension of $K$. Is that right?

Comment: What exactly is your argument to show that $K[X]/M$ is algebraic?

Comment: @David: Since $M$ is a maximal ideal, it is generated by a irreducible polynomial $g\in K[X]$. Hence $K[X]/M$ is isomorphic to a simple extension $K(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a zero of $g$. So $K[X]/M$ is algebraic.

Comment: Good!$\phantom{jwfljbjbfj}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a commutative ring and $f\in A[X]$ is a monic polynomial, then the ring extension $A\subset A[X]/(f)$ is integral.

In your case $K\subset K[X]/M$ is integral (algebraic) and then [every intermediate ring is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501160/suppose-k-f-is-an-algebraic-extension-of-fields-prove-that-if-r-is-a-ring-w), so $A/M\cap A$ is a field.